# UITableViewのEditbuttonitemが押されたタイミングを デリゲートメソッドなどで取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: swift, uikit

UITableViewの`Editbuttonitem`が押されたタイミングを
デリゲートメソッドなどで取得する方法はありますか？

UITableViewが編集モードに入る時に、
他のBarButtonItemを無効にしたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

`UITableView`には`editButtonItem`プロパティはないので、`UITableViewController`の話だと想定しますが、この場合は[UITableViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/)より、

> It implements the superclass method setEditing:animated: so that if a user taps an Edit|Done button in the navigation bar, the controller toggles the edit mode of the table.

`setEditing(_:animated:)`をオーバーライドすることで実現することができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！やってみます。